# Append only new records to table vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

I have a DB table in which new records get inserted in every 10 seconds.

Using vue and axios I am showing latest 20 records to the user in a HTML table.

At the created hook I have introduced a method which fetch data in every 5 second

```
 window.setInterval(() => {
            this.getRecentTrades()
          }, 5000)
```

Below is my table row code:

```
<tr v-for="recenttrade in recenttrades" :key='recenttrade.id' v-bind:class="recenttrade.side=='Buy' ? 'text-success' : 'text-danger'">
    <td>{{ recenttrade.price }} </td>
    <td>{{ recenttrade.size }} </td>
    <td>{{ recenttrade.timestamp }} </td>
    <td>{{ recenttrade.side }} </td>
</tr>
```

How can I comparison old records with the new records and only append the new records to the HTML table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html section replacing array it seems like the best solution is simply to reassign the local value with one from api. Vue will automagically use its change detection and rerender only items, that didn't belong to the table in previous update cycle.

Comment: Thanks Martin... it worked fine. You saved me a function which would be calculating the difference of array and pushing new items.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a function to get the difference between two arrays

```
function arrayDiff(a, b, key) {
    return [
        ...a.filter(x => !b.map(i => i[key]).includes(x[key])),
        ...b.filter(x => !a.map(i => i[key]).includes(x[key]))
    ];
}
```

and try something like this in your getRecentTrades function

```
getRecentTrades(){

    let that = this;     
    apiCall.then(data => {
       let diff = arrayDiff(that.recenttrades, data, 'id');
       that.recenttrades.push(...diff);
    })

}
```

I think you need to find a better way to do this because depending of how many records you fetch along the time, you could have a performance problems.

Comment: Thanks leocoder for your solution, you can check the accepted answer and there is no need to go for any explicit function

Answer (score 0):

You could just replace the data every time you call `getRecentTrades()`.  Since you are going to be adding to the list, only the new items need to be rendered.

Edit: Below comment is right, Vue won't need to re-render list items that were already there, based on the `:key` binding. That makes the solution of just replacing the data even better, since it only renders the new stuff anyways.

Comment: Not true, check my answer for explanation.

Comment: Thanks! Forgot that's exactly what `:key` is for